# Removing whitespace between consecutive numbers

Tags: c#, regex

I have a string, from which I want to remove the whitespaces *between the numbers*:

```
string test = "Some Words 1 2 3 4";
string result = Regex.Replace(test, @"(\d)\s(\d)", @"$1$2");
```

the expected/desired result would be:

```
"Some Words 1234"
```

but I retrieve the following:

```
"Some Words 12 34"
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Further examples:

```
Input:  "Some Words That Should not be replaced 12 9 123 4 12"
Output: "Some Words That Should not be replaced 129123412"

Input:  "test 9 8"
Output: "test 98"

Input:  "t e s t 9 8"
Output: "t e s t 98"

Input:  "Another 12 000"
Output: "Another 12000"
```

Comment: For the fun, [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c7l2Dw) is a regex-free solution. I think a Regex is a better solution.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Regex.Replace continues to search *after* the previous match:

```
Some Words 1 2 3 4
           ^^^
         first match, replace by "12"

Some Words 12 3 4
             ^
             +-- continue searching here

Some Words 12 3 4
              ^^^
            next match, replace by "34"
```

You can use a [zero-width positive lookahead assertion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/grouping-constructs-in-regular-expressions#zero-width-positive-lookahead-assertions) to avoid that:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(test, @"(\d)\s(?=\d)", @"$1");
```

Now the final digit is *not* part of the match:

```
Some Words 1 2 3 4
           ^^?
         first match, replace by "1"

Some Words 12 3 4
            ^
            +-- continue searching here

Some Words 12 3 4
            ^^?
            next match, replace by "2"

...
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can run the original regex twice. Though a positive lookahead is probably always the best option.

Answer (score 44):

Your regex consumes the digit on the right. `(\d)\s(\d)` matches and captures `1` in `Some Words 1 2 3 4` into Group 1, then matches 1 whitespace, and then matches and consumes (i.e. adds to the match value and advances the regex index) `2`. Then, the regex engine tries to find another match from the current index, that is already after `1 2`. So, the regex does not match `2 3`, but finds `3 4`.

Here is [your regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SIYlvb/1/) and a diagram showing that:

[image]

Also, see the process of matching here:

[image]

Use lookarounds instead that are *non-consuming*:

```
(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JXnsdM/2)

[image]

**Details**

- `(?<=\d)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location in string immediately preceded with a digit
- `\s+` - 1+ whitespaces
- `(?=\d)` - a positive lookahead that matches a location in string immediately followed with a digit.

C# demo:

```
string test = "Some Words 1 2 3 4";
string result = Regex.Replace(test, @"(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)", "");
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/VM64Yv):

```
var strs = new List<string> {"Some Words 1 2 3 4", "Some Words That Should not be replaced 12 9 123 4 12", "test 9 8", "t e s t 9 8", "Another 12 000" };
foreach (var test in strs) 
{
    Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(test, @"(?<=\d)\s+(?=\d)", ""));
}
```

Output:

```
Some Words 1234
Some Words That Should not be replaced 129123412
test 98
t e s t 98
Another 12000
```

Comment: (Woah, those visual representations are neat - how'd you get those? I don't see them on https://regex101.com, or am I overlooking something?  I found the debugger, but not the "workflow" one)

Comment: (Sorry for derailing - I don't see it. Here's a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RCL1Q.jpg). To clarify, I'm looking for [this thingy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ProHy.png). )

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and which tool is it to see regular expression matching in process ?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I used [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/SIYlvb/1/debugger) debugger.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for informing that, i was never aware, there is one