# How to remove multiple spaces between numbers using a single re.sub

Tags: python, regex, replace

I would like to remove spaces between numbers using a single re.sub. With the following commands:

```
import re

print(re.sub('([0-9,.]) ([0-9,.])','\\1\\2',str("11 222")))

print(re.sub('([0-9,.]) ([0-9,.])','\\1\\2',str("11 222 33")))

print(re.sub('([0-9,.]) ([0-9,.])','\\1\\2',str("11 222 33 4")))

print(re.sub('([0-9,.]) ([0-9,.])','\\1\\2',str("11 222 33 4 55")))

print(re.sub('([0-9,.]) ([0-9,.])','\\1\\2',str("11 222 33 4 55 6")))

print(re.sub('([0-9,.]) ([0-9,.])','\\1\\2',str("11 222 33 4 55 6 77")))
```

I can however remove only spaces if there are more that one successive numbers:

```
11222
1122233
11222334
11222334 55
11222334 556
11222334 556 77
```

But how to remove also spaces with only one number, so that the result of command like

```
print(re.sub('([0-9,.]) ([0-9,.])','\\1\\2',str("11 222 33 4 55 6 77")))
```

would be

```
1122233455677
```

?

Comment: Related [post in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54883192/3832970).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using lookarounds to detect the numbers surrounding a space:

```
print(re.sub('(?<=\\d) (?=\\d)','',str("11 222 33 4 55 6 77")))

1122233455677
```

The idea here is for each space we look behind and assert that a digit is present, and also we look ahead and assert that a digit is present.

Note that this answer won't remove spaces which might appear on either end of the string, but then again those spaces are not between numbers.

Comment: This solution seems to work! So I could not use overlapping groups with successive match instances. This different approach, which uses look aheads instead of overlapping groups, works exactly as desired.

Comment: @Heikki The limitation of your current approach is that it only works if all spaces are surrounded by islands of numbers of two or more (except maybe for the start and end).  This is because once the regex engine consumes a number, it can't be reused.  Lookarounds are a good option here because they assert, but do not consume, so the same number can conceptually be used twice.

Comment: For completeness, the regex of the question hints that I wanted to take away spaces also between numbers and delimiters. Therefore, I finally end up to the following regular expression: `re.sub('(?<=[0-9,.]) (?=[0-9,.])','',"11 . 222 33 4 55 6 77")`

Comment: I edited the question to include numbers and decimal separators, but exclude other characters.

Comment: @Heikki Nice.  You should not change your question after many other people have answered it.

Comment: @Heikki To clarify what Tim said, editing the question is fine, as long as you don't change the actual question. The edit you made changed the question too much, which also would've invalidated the answers. You're welcome to improve your post at any time, as long as that doesn't change the question itself. The main exception here is if the question got closed, in those cases the question itself needs to be changed to fit various SE criteria. if you have a separate question that arises after this one, [ask] a new one. The [editing guide](/help/editing) also covers this (probably better too)

Answer (score 0):

There are several expressions to grasp the digits. In this case, I find the simplest code in [ref](https://lzone.de/examples/Python%20re.sub). It could get rid of other characters.

```
print(re.sub(r'\s','',str("11 222 33 4 55")))
```

Comment: I wanted to avoid removing spaces from other than numbers and decimal separators.

Comment: This should work for dot symbol. print(re.sub('( )(\d)','\\2',"11 222 33 4 55 . 6 77"))