# JavaScript regex for adding space between numbers and operator symbols in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string containing numbers and operator symbols for example like this: `99*8998+-999`
I need to have a space between an operator and adjacent digit like this: `99 * 8998 +- 999`

I tried JavaScript `replaceAll` with `regex`: `/(\d+)([/*+-]+)(\d*)/g`
But this regex works fine until there are no non adjacent operator symbols in the string.

For example refer following working and non working conditions.

```
"998998+999".replaceAll(/(\d+)([/*+-]+)(\d*)/g, "$1 $2 $3")  
=> "998998 + 999" // Works as expected

"998998+-999".replaceAll(/(\d+)([/*+-]+)(\d*)/g, "$1 $2 $3") 
=> "998998 +- 999" // Works as expected

"99*8998+-999".replaceAll(/(\d+)([/*+-]+)(\d*)/g, "$1 $2 $3") 
=> "99 * 8998+-999" // Does not works as expected. Expected: "99 * 8998 +- 999"
```

The regex seems to return after first match without capturing next one even with the `global` flag.

What could be wrong?

Comment: You can change the last group in a positive lookahead `(\d+)([\/*+-]+)(?=\d)` https://regex101.com/r/v53RVq/1

Comment: Maybe just `.replace(/\s*([\/*+-]+)\s*/g, " $1 ") `

Comment: The trailing `(\d*)` doesn't make much sense, because that section will match regardless, may as well just leave it off?

Comment: Thanks both of you, just curious why my initial regex does not capture multiple match? Or it was not getting matched at all further?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54883163/removing-whitespace-between-consecutive-numbers/54883192#54883192

Answer (score 2):

Reason why your approach didn't work because your regex is matching and consuming characters in expression such as: `12+34-1` which has a overlapping match. Due to that you will have to use zero-width lookahead which will do only lookahead but won't consume characters from input.

You may match using this regex:

```
/(\d)(\+-|[\/*+-])(?=\d)/g
```

Replace using `"$1 $2 "`

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AOHG6g/2)

There might be other 2 character operators for your case. I have used only `+-` in my example above. You can add then in alternations in 2nd capture group above.

**RegEx Details:**

- `(\d)`: Match and capture a digit in group #1
- `(\+-|[\/*+-])`: Match `+-` or a single character operator `/`, `*`, `+` or `-`
- `(?=\d)`: Positive lookahead to assert that there is a digit ahead